# Feature click listener issue android GeoJsonLayer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, geojson

Hello I'm working with google map android api and I'm using google maps android geojson utility. I'm adding 3 layers of geojson into the map only the **road_layer**(LineString) have feature click event. The click event is working fine until I'm adding the **samsad_boundary_layer**(Polygon). The issue is if the **samsad_boundary_layer** feature is clicked it's triggering the **road_layer** feature click event although the layer(samsad_boundary_layer) have no feature click event.

```
private void showBoundery(){
    try {
        samsad_boundary_layer=new GeoJsonLayer(mMap,R.raw.samsad_boundary,MapActivity.this); //1st Layer
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    samsad_boundary_layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle().setZIndex(-12f);
    GeoJsonPolygonStyle polygonStyle=samsad_boundary_layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
    polygonStyle.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    polygonStyle.setStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
    samsad_boundary_layer.addLayerToMap();
}

private void retrieveFileFromResource() {
    try {
        temp_layer=new GeoJsonLayer(mMap,R.raw.area_survey,this); //2nd Layer
        temp_layer.addLayerToMap();
        road_layer=new GeoJsonLayer(mMap,R.raw.road_survey,this); //3rd Layer
        road_layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new Layer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
                if (feature!=null){
                    Iterator<HashMap> flavoursIter = feature.getProperties().iterator();
                   while (flavoursIter.hasNext()){
                        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)flavoursIter.next();
                        //Log.v("SURVEYOR_FEATURE",entry.getKey().toString()+":"+entry.getValue());

                    }

                }
            }
        });
        GeoJsonLineStringStyle lineStyle=road_layer.getDefaultLineStringStyle();
        lineStyle.setZIndex(10f);
        lineStyle.setWidth(2f);
        lineStyle.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green));
        road_layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get the answer.

Comment: I asked the same in the github as well but this issue till date is unsolved.

Comment: Did you found any solutions ?

Comment: @podgradle well no instead I used a layer stack because I noticed that the click function only works for the top layer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding 3 layers on map separately, traverse through all and create single layer.
Then add layer to map and set feature click listener. Handle onFeatureClick accordingly.